# Turning frequency table into raw data in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 2-column matrix: Column 1 has events (in the form of integers), column 2 counts how frequently those events occurred. I would like to turn this back into the raw data, effectively the inverse of `tabulate()`. I.e. turn [0 4; 1 2; 2 2; 3 1; 4 0] into [0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3]. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
a = [0 4; 1 2; 2 2; 3 1; 4 0];
```

Then you can simply use the 2nd column as the number of repeats and the first column as the values for `repelem`

```
b = repelem( a(:,1), a(:,2) ).';
% >> b = [0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     3]
```

With the `.'` as optional to transpose the result from a column to a row.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million for that Wolfie

Comment: @Matt If the answer fully solves your issue, consider marking it as accepted (green tick mark)